# Locker Service problem - jQuery offset() returning 0 values for left and top

Tags: jquery, lightning, locker-service

I've been trying to get the fullcalendar scheduler plugin to work with Locker Service and one of the issues I found was that the jQuery function offset() is always returning 0 for top and left.

To reproduce, I created a container div and a div element within with relative positioning.

```
<div class="containing">
    <div class="testClass"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.THIS.containing{
   top: 21px; 
   left: 50px;
   position: relative;
}

.THIS .testClass{
   top: 20px; 
   left: 50px;
   position: relative;

   /** giving it substance for visuals **/
   width: 100px;
   height: 10px;
   background: #000;

}
```

Having Locker Service activated, **$('.testClass').offset()** gives me **Object{left:0, top: 0}**. 
jQuery version is **v2.2.4**.

Is this a known issue? If so, when can we expect a fix for this?

As a workaround, I'm using the following script to calculate the offset: (modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777506/offsettop-vs-jquery-offset-top)

```
  var box = { top: 0, left: 0 };
  var docElem = document.documentElement;

  // BlackBerry 5, iOS 3 (original iPhone)
  if ( typeof elem.getBoundingClientRect !== "undefined" ) {
    box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  }

  return {
    top: box.top  + ( elem.scrollTop || docElem.scrollTop )  - ( docElem.clientTop  || 0 ),
    left: box.left + ( elem.scrollLeft || docElem.scrollLeft ) - ( docElem.clientLeft || 0 )
  }
```

Hope this helps anyone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LockerService used to return a clone of the document when `document.documentElement` was called. This caused issues because certain values, like `clientHeight`, would get reset to 0 during the clone rather than keep the original value. This has been fixed now and APIs such as jQuerys `offset()` should function properly.

If this is still broken without the workaround let us know and we'll investigate further.