# How to find which button in clicked in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm creating a List that has one or more buttonIcons in the end.I'm creating these buttons dynamically with `$A.createComponent`.
While clicking the button,I need to find which button is clicked and then finding its position with `getBoundingClientRect()`.
How can I do it? 
I tried `event.getSource()`,`event.currentTarget` & `event.target`.
Nothing helped!
Or Is there any ways to find the position of a element in lightning.
(I need to show a popup relative to the button's position,can't use lightning:helptext)

Comment: did you try `event.getSource().getElement()` too?

Comment: btw. this question might be somewhat related to yours: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133422/locker-service-problem-jquery-offset-returning-0-values-for-left-and-top

Comment: Yes I tried,It says `event.getSource().getElement()` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First find the body of the parent component of the dynamically created components.
2. Then find the button and `getBoundingClientRect` [Refer this QA](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145433/problems-finding-a-dynamically-created-child-component),

`

```
findButton : function(cmp) {
        var parentElement = cmp.find("parent").get("v.body");
        console.log("child 1",parentElement[buttonIndex].find("buttonId").getBoundingClientRect());
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the below code, It will help you to find which button you clicked.Can you please add your code snippets.

```
 <aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="whichButton" type="String" />

<p>You clicked: {!v.whichButton}</p>
  <ui:button aura:id="button1" label="Click me" press="{!c.nameThatButton}"/>
   <ui:button aura:id="button2" label="Click me too" press="
        {!c.nameThatButton}"/>
     </aura:component>
```

Javascript:

```
 ({
     nameThatButton : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var whichOne = event.getSource().getLocalId();
    console.log(whichOne);
    cmp.set("v.whichButton", whichOne); } })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm dynamically creating the buttons with same `aura:id`.So can't do it with LocalId.

Comment: Okay. Can you please add your code snippets.

Comment: I did it with dynamically creating a new component instead of dynamically creating  a button.Thanks